# react native using like web-based ajax function

Tags: android, ajax, reactjs, native

Before a user clicks on dropdown

[image]

When user click on the dropbox value, my android apps will display a table below with content accordingly, like showing up the table Guest Information&payment as shown in the following image.

[image]

Please give me some ideas how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This website is designed for people to ask specific questions about problems they are facing. You should probably find a discussion forum to ask this question. Good luck.

Comment: This is a discussion forum I found to ask question. Well, I try to upload picture for better understanding.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a discussion forum, really. It's for tackling specific technical issues. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you don't understand my problem, please ask for clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

First, set the state like `this.setState({guestInfoTable : <View> Content </View>})`

And then, add `{ this.state.guestInfoTable  }` in render function and it works for me! Thanks for viewing.

Comment: Fortunately, my colleague knew how to do it. :)

Comment: the keyword to utilize is just 'state', quite easy =)

Comment: Anyway, there is another problem. I got another warning message.

warning:each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Comment: This is the code which got problem.


   for (var i=0; i < this.state.guest.value; i++){

          returnValue.push( <View style={styles.input}>
                <View style={styles.tableBox4}>
                    <Text style={styles.field}>{i}</Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.field} underlineColorAndroid={'white'} key={i} />
                    <TextInput keyboardType ={'numeric'} style={styles.field} underlineColorAndroid={'white'} key={i} />
                </View>
            </View> );

        }